# How to read value using NSUserDefaults from one view to another view?

Tags: iphone

I used NSUserDefaults to store a value. I store some integer value in NSUserDefaults like as follows in first view.

I declared in interface file as follows..

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs;
    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet NSUserDefaults *prefs;
```

Then I used in class file as follows

```
   @synthesize passwordfield,prefs;
```

here passwordfield is the name of UITextField

```
NSInteger myInteger = [passwordfield.text integerValue];
[prefs setInteger:myInteger forKey:@"integerKey"];
[prefs synchronize];
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
NSLog(@"My integer Value: %d",myInt);
```

Then I move to next view using navigation controller.

But I can't read NSUserDefaults's value from the first view.

I used code like as follows in second view.

```
PasswordCheckViewController *nextController = [[PasswordCheckViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PasswordCheckViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"Pass in Next: %d",[nextController.prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"]);
```

But the output as follows.

```
 Pass in Next: 0
```

How can I get the value from the first view to second view using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: How is "prefs" set and where is it declared?  Why do you say `nextController.prefs` instead of just `prefs`?  If prefs is a property of PasswordCheckViewController, how is it initialized?

Comment: hi aBitObvious, i edit my question now.. please help me.. How to get values from one view to another view using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Why is prefs an IBOutlet?  You can just use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` instead of declaring properties everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong,`NSUserDefaults` are not `IBOutlets`,an `IBOutlet` is used to refer an InterfaceBuilder control.

`NSUserDefault` is usually used to store some preference values.
Typically, you use the `NSUserDefaults` class by invoking the `standardUserDefaults` class method to get an NSUserDefaults object. This method returns a global `NSUserDefaults` object with a search list already initialized. Use the `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:` methods to get and set default values. Note that a default’s value can be only property list objects: `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`
   In your case you are creating an `IBOutlet` which is not needed. Do like this

```
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
  NSInteger myInteger = [passwordfield.text integerValue];
  [prefs setObject:myInteger forKey:@"integerKey"];
  NSInteger myInt = [prefs objectForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

this will give you a synchronized `NSUserDefaults` so that you dont need to store anything as an ivar.
You can access the value of the object from any classes inside your app

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing view and view controllers. So you can get desired view controller from navigation controller and get desired view from it in case that views didn't unloaded.
For example if self is second view controller and you want to read from first view controller:

```
MyFirstViewController *vc = (MyFirstViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: indexOfFirst];
// ... now copy your prefs from first to second
self.prefs = vc.prefs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the function where u need to get the value using `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"a"];
```